# Plot 3d volumetric data represented by a 3D numpy array

Tags: python, vtk, mayavi

I've seen that vtkplotter supports a wide range of volumetric image formats, but does it support plotting numpy arrays? I have an image in a .mhd format that I converted to .npz file and would like to plot it using the mentioned library. Is there a way to do so?

```
import numpy as np
data = np.zeros((3,3,3))
# how to plot this?
```

If you know any other tools for visualizing volumetric data, suited for medical analysis, please tell so. I've tried mayavi but it consumes so much memory that it crashes my computer.

Comment: You should check the [examples page](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/examples.html) to get a better grip of the kind of plot that would work for you. Particularly, the [MRI example](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_mri.html#example-mri) uses iso-surface and cut-planes at the same time

Comment: Can you provide your mayavi snippet which crashes?

Answer (score 5):

You can use numpy_support to convert numpy arrays to vtkImageData (i.e. a VTK 3D image).

An example follows, there's a numpy warning about type conversion: I don't think it's relevant but I'm not a python guru...

```
from vtk.util import numpy_support
import vtk
import numpy as np

data = np.zeros((3,3,3))

# vtkImageData is the vtk image volume type
imdata = vtk.vtkImageData()
# this is where the conversion happens
depthArray = numpy_support.numpy_to_vtk(data.ravel(), deep=True, array_type=vtk.VTK_DOUBLE)

# fill the vtk image data object
imdata.SetDimensions(data.shape)
imdata.SetSpacing([1,1,1])
imdata.SetOrigin([0,0,0])
imdata.GetPointData().SetScalars(depthArray)

# f.ex. save it as mhd file
writer = vtk.vtkMetaImageWriter()
writer.SetFileName("test.mhd")
writer.SetInputData(imdata)
writer.Write()
```

... and to visualize vtk volume data you can use Paraview.